# Bootstrap 3.1.1 Javascript not working in my rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I placed the bootstrap css and js files in their respective directories app/assets/stylesheets app/assets/javascripts

and modified application.js and application.css to include the bootstrap files respectively

application.css:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap.min
 */
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree .
```

The css is loading fine while the javascript is not. So things like dropdowns do not work.

Did I miss something

**EDIT ANSWERED!:**

My low rep won't allow me to answer my own question so I will posted it here:

By removing

```
//= require_tree .
```

from application.js and instead specifying the bootstrap.min.js file fixed the problem.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
```

I made a quick test rails app with a static homepage and installed the bootstrap files again and got the same issue. I originally thought that other files in my javascripts directory were conflicting with bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js but they were not as I was able to replicate this problem on a new barebones app.

Comment: If you have `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` file on your stylesheets don't add `*= require bootstrap.min` and `//= require bootstrap.min`. `*= require_tree .` will call all css files on css folder and `//= require_tree .` will call all js files on js folder

Comment: Could you see on console, when you click dropdown? if error appear post it.

Comment: That is good to know. Realizing the implication of *= require_tree helped me solve my own problem. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand what the original problem was... since you were requiring the correct files in the original try also.

Comment: I'm not sure either which is why I made a barebones app to see if installing bootstrap on a clean app would replicate the same problem. It did have the same javascript issue, so I just did some guess work. Perhaps it's an issue with rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You probably shouldn't be requiring both the bootstrap files in your application.[js/css] file, if you have already placed said files in your app/assests/[javascripts/stylesheets] directories, because anything within those directories will automatically be included by the `require_tree .` line in the application.[js/css] files. This is the "newer" rails asset pipeline, which will take all of the required js/css and minify it into a single js file and single css file. The `require_tree .` directive requires all the files within the "tree" of the assets/[javascripts/stylesheets] directory in question.
2. From the explanation in 1, you probably gathered that you shouldn't remove the `require_tree .` lines from your application. files

Simply add back in the `require_tree .` lines into both the application. files, and then make sure that both bootstrap files are in their respective assets/ directory.

Cheers!

Comment: @Spundun, I can't comment on other people's comments due to my low rep, but the reason the original app didn't work is because the duplicate includes cause a conflict that rails resolves by dropping both of the conflicting files, from my understanding, which means that having duplicate includes actually results in _neither_ of them being successful